# Empty List of String appears null when initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to insert a string into my list of strings.

I initialize my string like so in a class called globals that holds this list.

`List<String> myStringList = [];`

Then in my controller class I am trying to insert a string into the list like so.

`globals.myStringList.add(stringToAdd);`

But I get an error that says the list is null. Not sure if I am initializing it wrong since it appears this is the way to initialize an empty list.

Globals Class

```
import 'package:flutter_project/models/categories.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/models/videos.dart';
List<String> reports = [];
List<Video> videos = [];
List<Category> categories = [];
List<String> userSearches = <String>[];
bool inSearch = false;
```

Comment: You have initialized it right but the matter is where you have initialized.Can you show the full code of that `globals` class

Comment: The globals class just holds some variables that I need to reference throughout the program.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, I was initializing my string incorrectly. It has to be done like so.

`List<String> myStringList = <String>[];`

Comment: This is the right way List<String> myStringList = [];-- How you found error here?

Comment: Yeah thought it was fixed but it turns out it's still throwing the error that it is null when I reference it for the first time.

Comment: Okay I think I have the answer, because the globals class isn't really initialized due to it just holding variables it's never really set equal to nothing. So I just run a check to see if it's null and if it is then I set it to empty and it appears to be working.

Comment: @poomulus thanks bro, for your question and answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make the variable static so that it can be accessible by the class name